# Print difference between two tuples

Tags: python, tuples, difference

How can I print just the differences between two tuples?

```
 >>>a=(1,2,3,4)
 >>>b=(2,3,5,6)
```

If the tuples are as above then the expected output is `(1,4,5,6)`. The compare functions can only compare but could not find the differences.

The tuples are generated by `MySQLdb` python library. The queries being executed produces a fair amount of data.

```
In [13]: c.execute(query)
Out[13]: 86844L
In [14]: qop1 = c.fetchall()
In [19]: len(qop1)
Out[19]: 86844
```

So if I compare every tuple with custom code it will take a lot of time. Can I achieve this an efficient way like an inbuilt python library?

Comment: How do you define the *difference* between two tuples? Is `(1, 2, 3)` the same as `(3, 2, 1)`? Do you want an *edit distance* or similar?

Comment: Do you mean the expected output to be `(1,1,2,2)`? The output you wrote is neither the component difference nor the difference treating each tuple as a number.

Comment: I think OP wants to display the values that are not in common between the two tuples.

Comment: I think you are talking about set differences, not tuple differences.

Comment: I want to compare and print the content of the tuples only. Is there any inbuilt functions for that? I mean if I compare with custom code it would take a lot of time as the tuple is generated by 'cursor.fetchall()' of mysqldb

Comment: Most likely the downvotes come frome these 2 reasons (and given these, it's normal to be downvoted): 1. Because the question wasn't clear (just look at the amount of guessing people had to do) and 2, you didn't show any research effort.

Answer (score 13):

You want the [Symmetric Difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) -- elements in either set but not in the intersection. This can be done by:

```
set(a) ^ set(b)
```

or:

```
set(a).symmetric_difference(set(b))
```

Comment: `set(a).symmetric_difference(b)` is actually enough. Nice use of the xor operator by the way.

Comment: Doesn't `symmetric_difference` require both `a` and `b` to be sorted, though? If you don't make `b` a set you would need to run it through `sorted(b)` (unless you know `b` is always sorted and does not have duplicates).

Comment: Sets are hash tables so they're not sorted. Values just end up in a certain order depending on their corresponding hash values, but this order is not guaranteed to be the same as `sorted(s)`. In any case, order and duplicates are not an issue as the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) states  `the non-operator versions of union(), intersection(), difference(), and symmetric_difference() will accept any iterable as an argument` (since version 2.3.1)

Answer (score 3):

From your example one can deduce that you are asking about **symmetric difference of sets** and in python you can simply do

```
a=(1,2,3,4)
b=(2,3,5,6)
print tuple(set(a) ^ set(b))
```